# Google map API key not working properly in android app but IP address works properly

Tags: android, api, dictionary, key

[image: Got error here]**Downloaded URL: {   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 000.00.000.00, with empty referer",   "routes" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}**

i got this Error when i put SHA-1 and Package name to generate key , key generated but when i use it and run application some times it works limited (PlaceAutoComplete work) but on selection No Response and some times PlaceAutoComplete Also not works (when i write a single character PlaceAutoSearch option went closed),

if i give IP address of my device it works properly with tha same nothing to b change , just need to change google map API key settings from Android to IP address

Why it asked for IP authorization? why it not works on SHA-1 and Package name in Android

Help me Please

Comment: please share your log as well

Comment: @RajendraMahato Please see Attached image

Comment: ISSUE RESOLVED 
Google map received requests from both web and Android so it was not working , when I select Android Apps in GOOGLE MAP API Settings it works on android but web gives Error and when i select IP web works but android gives error 
Google needs for both
Thanks